# Vector differential equation, am I missing something?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve this vector differential equation. x'=Ax where

A=$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

My eigenvalues are -3,3,-1. I get eigen vectors, respectively: $[0,0,k],[k_1,k_1,0],[k_2,k_2,0]$

So I then get $e^{At}$= $P\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-3} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & e^{-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$

where P is $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Then I multiply them all out.

Is this right so far? Can someone maybe continue this? I'm not sure what I should expect my final answer to look like.

Comment: Someone thinks I should have an initial condition...

Comment: And $t$s should show up in your matrix.

Comment: This reply is not a solution, nor it is a hint unfortunately. Solving vector differential equations is a straightforward but tedious work, all steps of which is known and well described, involving matrix multiplication and integration. Kinda rude to ask someone to do that work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find the characteristic polynomial: $$p(t) = \begin{vmatrix} 1-t & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 1-t & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -3-t\end{vmatrix} = -(t+3)((1-t)^2-4) = -(t+3)(-t+3)(-t-1),$$ so we have eigenvalues $3,-3$ and $-1$, good job. Let's check the eigenvectors now.

- $\lambda_1 = 3$: $$(A-3\,{\rm Id}){\bf v} = {\bf 0} \iff \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ gives us $a = b $ and $c = 0$. So write up ${\bf v}_1 = (1,1,0)$.
- $\lambda_2 = -3$: $$(A+3\,{\rm Id}){\bf v} = {\bf 0} \iff \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$gives us $a = b = 0$ so we take ${\bf v}_2 = (0,0,1)$.
- $\lambda_3 = -1$ : $$(A+\,{\rm Id}){\bf v} = {\bf 0} \iff \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$gives us $b = -a$ and $c = 0$, so we take ${\bf v}_3 = (1,-1,0)$.

The general solution is: $${\bf x}(t) = c_1e^{\lambda_1t}{\bf v}_1 + c_2e^{\lambda_2t}{\bf v}_2+c_3e^{\lambda_3t}{\bf v}_3, \quad c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \Bbb R.$$
(Look at the ${\bf v}_j$ as columns, if you want.)

Comment: how sure of this are you? If correct, I appreciate your willingness to help me!

Comment: Sure exactly of what?

Comment: of this answer... It looks correct to me, but are you 100%? I got the same eigenvectors too, i dont know.

Comment: I highly doubt that I've made any mistakes there. However, you can check it yourself writing ${\bf x}(t)$ as a column vector, and verifying that ${\bf x}'(t) = A{\bf x}(t)$.

Comment: never mind. i do

Comment: What I am actually doing is finding basis for the eigenspaces. Note: $$ \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \iff \begin{cases}-2a+2b = 0 \\2a-2b = 0 \\ -6c = 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: The important is finding a basis for the eigenspace. Both vectors span it, they are multiples. You can use either one.